# Need assistance to create a simple SQL database. Error is as follows: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just need a little help with an error I am receiving when trying to create a table in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. The table I am trying to construct is: (This is only a small portion of the database which contains multiple tables similar to this one being constructed)

```
create table Holidays (
   staff_ID numeric(10) foreign key,
   start_Date date,
   fin_Date date,
   holiday_Type char(100),
   reason nvarchar(100),
);
```

The error I am receiving is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

NOTE: I have created tables before in a similar fashion to this, and have looked over them to compare the differences (to which I can see is almost none).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The syntax error is caused because the last column has a comma after it - `reason nvarchar(100), );` Remove the comma and it should be fine - `reason nvarchar(100));`.

Comment: ***PLEASE*** - do **NOT** use `char(100)` !! That'll be a fixed-width column, the values are always going to be padded with spaces to the defined length of 100 characters .... use `varchar(100)` instead! `char(x)` should only be used for short (1-5 chars), fixed-length codes, like ISO currency codes (3 chars) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one "," extra on the end , also your foreign key mentioned badly.
Try this:

```
create table Holidays ( 
staff_ID numeric(10) foreign key references Table(Column), 
start_Date date, fin_Date date, holiday_Type char(100), 
reason nvarchar(100))
```

Comment: Thank you heaps. and thanks to everyone for their input. I am fairly new to writing in SQL. You guys have helped a lot :D. It was the foreign key that was really causing the problems for me and now that I've fixed that, as well as the commas, everything is working well.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma after your last column definition. Try this:

```
create table Holidays (
staff_ID numeric(10) foreign key,
start_Date date,
fin_Date date,
holiday_Type char(100),
reason nvarchar(100) -- removed comma from here
);
```